# AzureWorkerHost get the uri after startup for Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am trying to create a ASP.Net with neo4jclient project to be hosted on the Azure and am kind of unable to grasp how to do the following:

1. get hold of an neo4j rest endpoint address once the worker role has started. I think I am seeing a different address each time the emulator spins up a instance of worker role. I believe that i'll need this to create an client somewhat like this

`neo4jClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http ://localhost:7474/db/data"));`

so any thoughts on how to get hold of the uri after the neo4j is deployed by AzureWorkerHost.

1. Also how is the graph database persisted on the blob store, in the example its always deploying a new instance of pristine db in the zip and updating, which is probably not correct. I am unable to understand where to configure this.

BTW I am using the Neo4j 2.0 M06 and when it runs in emulator, I get an endpoint somewhat like this `http://127.255.0.1:20000` in the emulator log but i am unable to access it from my base machine.

any clue what might be going on here?

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AzureWorkerHost](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4j.Server.AzureWorkerHost) was a proof of concept that hasn't been touched in a year.

The GitHub readme says:

> Just past alpha. Some known deficiencies still. Not quite beta.

You likely don't want to use it.

The preferred way of hosting on Azure these days seems to be IaaS approach inside a VM. (There's a preconfigured one in VM Depot, but that's a little old now too.)

Or, you could use a hosted endpoint from somebody like [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com/).

To answer you question generally though, Azure manages all the endpoints. The worker roles says "hey, I need an endpoint to bind to!" and Azure works that out for it.

Then, you query this from the Web role by interrogating `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.Roles`.

Comment: Thanks @Tatham, I see that GrapheneDB is still in its Beta, bit curious if we can risk our new solution on it!. however would there not be a performance issue if i start making a calls to GraphenDB from within my Azure business logic? what would be your preferred way to host a neo4j server while using Azure for my portal when considering cost vs performance.

Comment: Afaik they have already several production customers running on their platform. I'd say just talk to them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely not want to use the AzureWorkerHost for a production scenario, as the instances in the deployed configuration will destroy your data when they are re-imaged.

Please review these slides that illustrate step-by-step deployment of a Windows Azure Virtual Machine image of Neo4j community edition.

http://de.slideshare.net/neo4j/neo4j-on-azure-step-by-step-22598695

A Neo4j 2.0 Community Virtual Machine image will be released with the official release build of Neo4j 2.0. If you plan to use more than 30GB of data storage, please be aware that the currently supported VM image in Windows Azure's image depot must be configured from console through remote SSH to Linux.

Continue with your development using `http://localhost:7474/` and then setup the VM when you are ready for a staging or production build to be deployed.

Also you can use Heroku's free Neo4j database deployment but you must configure the basic authentication for your GraphClient connection in Neo4jClient.

Comment: Thanks @KennyBastani, I had completely overlooked that part.